# Why are the images produced from a numpy array incorrect

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have written a python program which takes x, y, c values (c being charge) from a particle detector and converts them to grey scale heat map images. An example of what the program produces is below. What should be shown is several clusters of grey-white areas on a black background representing particle collisions with the screen. I know this because the PIXELMAN program which we use with the particle detector shows what it looks like, my program just lets you do it without the detector plugged in.

[image: Incorrect image]

```
def heatMap(self):
    xlist=[]
    ylist=[]    
    clist=[]
    directory = str(self.varRun.get())
    if directory == "None selected" :
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("ERROR", "No run was selected")
    else:
        filename = askopenfilename(title = "Choose a new Image to import", initialdir=directory)
        if filename[-4:] != ".txt":
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("ERROR", "You must select a .txt image")
        else:
            with open(filename,'r') as f:
                reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
                for x, y, c in reader:
                    xlist.append(int(x))
                    ylist.append(int(y)) 
                    clist.append(float(c))


        #np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)

        maxC = max(clist)

        array = np.zeros((256, 256))
        for i in range (0, len(xlist)-1):
            rgbValue = (float(clist[i]) / float(maxC)) * 255
            array[ylist[i],xlist[i]] = rgbValue
        array = sp.ndimage.zoom(array, 2, order=0)
        imageFromArray = Image.fromarray(array, "1")

        imageFromArray.save(str(filename[:-4] + ".png"))
        newPhoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageFromArray)
        self.ImageViewer.configure(image=newPhoImg)
        self.ImageViewer.image = newPhoImg
```

The routine which asks for the file and displays it is above. Any help with discovering why the image does not form properly is appreciated. I have checked that xlist, ylist and clist all get the correct values inserted into them from the text file I just don't know what goes wrong from there. A sample of an input file is:

```
2   0   43.000000
3   0   65.000000
4   0   67.000000
5   0   33.000000
7   0   44.000000
8   0   102.000000
9   0   59.000000
10  0   31.000000
11  0   42.000000
12  0   29.000000
13  0   125.000000
14  0   115.000000
...

247 255 38.000000
```

Obviously this continues all the way down to y values of 255

Now that this is solved two images produced were:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is `array[ylist[i], xlist[i]]` correct i.e. not other way around, `array[xlist[i], ylist[i]]`? Although the image would probably be just rotated.

Comment: I wonder if this is a `dtype` issue? Your code seems to be encoding its data as numbers less than 255, so you probably want to put `dtype=np.ubyte` or similar in your call to `np.zeros`, to avoid its default of double precision floats.

Comment: Can you share a sample input file?

Comment: It will not allow me to share an input file although I can show you a sample of one. The change in order of the lists would just cause a rotation so I don't think that is the key issue. I shall try the dtype idea

Comment: A small sample that someone can use to demonstrate the problem is sufficient.

Comment: The line `imageFromArray = Image.fromarray(array, "1")` seems strange.  `mode='1'` results in 1-bit pixels.  Is that really what you want?  (Also note that converting between PIL mode `'1'` and numpy arrays is buggy--e.g. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1228)

Comment: It would be good to narrow down whether the problem lies in generating the PIL `Image` object or in reading/normalizing the array. Have you tried [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)ing the array using matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, this line

```
    imageFromArray = Image.fromarray(array, "1")
```

is suspect.  You are converting a floating point array to a 1-bit image (see http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode).

Try changing that line to

```
    imageFromArray = Image.fromarray(array).convert('L')
```

Then `imageFromArray` will be an 8-bit image which can be saved as a PNG file.